# how to fix this HH FIXME [4410]?

Tags: hacklang

Trying to fix a HH complain... Basically the code is doing something similar to this

```
Sfirstgroup = idx($largegroup, "first");

$final_thing = null

if(HH\is_any_array(Sfirstgroup) && Sfirstgroup){

   /*HH_FIXME[4110] Error revealed by is_arry refining to varray_or_darray */

   $final_thing = idx(Sfirstgroup[0],"final_thing")

}
```

I think it must have some thing to with firstgroup[0] doesn't have a collection type. but couldn't figure out how to fix this...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have two type errors:

1. Indexing with square bracket syntax `$firstgroup[0]` doesn't work very well with the inferred type from `is_any_array`, which infers wildcard generics for the key type (i.e. it's a `KeyedContainer<_,_>`). Either change `$a[0]` to `idx($a, 0)` or use `is_vec_or_varray` if all your keys are `int`, since it refines to `vec<_>`.
2. You need to prove `$firstgroup[0]` is a `KeyedContainer` to use your second `idx` call for `$final_thing`. The refinement checks like `is_any_array` won't work on an indexed variable (like `$firstgroup[0]`), so you have to make a temporary variable to refine it.

All in all, here's one possible solution:

```
$firstgroup = idx($largegroup, "first");

$final_thing = null;

if(HH\is_vec_or_varray($firstgroup)){
    $first_item = $firstgroup[0];
    if(HH\is_any_array($first_item)) {
        $final_thing = idx($first_item,"final_thing");
    }
}
```